# How to fix “TypeError: 'Series' Objects are mutable”? in Python in relation to dataframes and dictionaries

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a for loop looping through an array with dataframes (sheets of an excel file) and I have my dictionary values where the keys are column names in a sheet and the values are classes. The reason being is that I have decided to use a template pattern and therefore the processData() et. all are methods that I have.

Some important information to note: mOAD is the dictionary and mywdf the data frame, basically I am trying to loop through an excel sheet and I do not know how many columns, which items in a dictionary beforehand, nor how many sheets there are before hand or which columns that will be in the sheet.

I have attempted putting in different conditions as well as changing the array index and looking up different solutions however nothing seems to apply or work in this case. For example: "Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed" error while asking a similar question doesn't provide a good answer and I cannot figure out what to do. I will show part of the dictionary and a sample concrete class for reference and then my loop.

```
mOAD = \
    {

    #here is sheet 1
    "AGE NOW"     : aNow(),
    "AGE AT DEATH": aAD(),
    "BIRTH DATE"  : bDay(),
    "DEATH DATE"  : deDay(),
    "MATCH TYPE"  : mType(),
    "GENDER"      : gender(),
    "MARITAL"     : mar(),
    }
#example of concrete class
class bDay(iterator):
    def processData(self):
       print("as")

   def evaluateData(self):
       print(" we")

   def explainData(self):
       print(" go")
#now the loop
 z = 1
while z < numSheet:


for i, j in mywdf[z].iterrows():
   # print(i)
   print(j)
   if i > 0:
    mOAD[j].processData()
    mOAD[j].evaluateData()
    mOAD[j].explainData()

z += 1
```

I would like it to ideally identify the column, and then for the corresponding column name call the functions from the concrete class. Sorry if it is confusing but I will try to clarify the best I can. This is the second time I've post this question because I really cannot find anything that works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `j` is a Series since your are iterating through the `rows` of a DataFrame. You cannot use an unhasable type as the key to a dictionary.

Comment: I was originally intending it to be a string so that when it gets the column name, it'll be the same as the key thus calling the value which is the concrete class.

Comment: Then perhaps you want `for j in mywdf[z].columns`? It's difficult to know exactly needs to happen here without some sample data in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I did that however it say's "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'", also I added an example of my concrete class.

Comment: @ALollz I also looked up ways to convert series objects to strings to remedy the problem but I haven't found anything I can use.